# Как при клике на ссылку показать значение href через alert?

Tags: html, jquery

```js
$(".link-moto").on("click", function() {
  alert($(this).html())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="link-moto" target="blank" href="https://www.harley-davidson.com/us/en/index.html">
  Harley-Davidson USA
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Для того что бы показать значение атрибута в [alert'е](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/alert), нужно сначала его получить:

```js
$("a").on("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  const href = $(this).attr("href")
  alert(href)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="link-moto" target="blank" href="https://www.harley-davidson.com/us/en/index.html">Harley-Davidson USA</a>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event - в лисе глобальный event может всё еще где-то не работать) `function (e) { e.preventDefault()`

Comment: Не знал - проверил. Оказалось, нет - https://i.gyazo.com/08ea3b7332502e4688395a0ab156b13b.png )